# Fontspec's WordSpace feature fails to work inside TikZ node with align=center

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, fontspec

Consider the following code, in which I am trying to change the `WordSpace` inside a Ti*k*Z node. With `align=flush left` it works fine; but with `align=center`, the `WordSpace` configuration no longer functions. Is this a bug or am I doing it wrongly?

(*The picture below shows the result under LuaLaTeX, with XeLaTeX the font `SourceSansPro` cannot be found.*)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,fontspec}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[text width=.3\pagewidth, align=flush left] {\fontspec{SourceSansPro}[WordSpace={5,1,1}] Some text for testing};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[text width=.3\pagewidth, align=center] {\fontspec{SourceSansPro}[WordSpace={5,1,1}] Some text for testing};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's happening when you use `align=flush center`?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you, this works fine. I didn't realize that there is also a `flush center` apart from `center`.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround with `\makebox` (I added `draw` just to show the node widths are the same):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,fontspec}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, text width=.3\pagewidth, align=flush left] {\fontspec{SourceSansPro}[WordSpace={5,1,1}]Some text for testing};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw] {\makebox[.3\pagewidth][c]{\fontspec{SourceSansPro}[WordSpace={5,1,1}]Some text for testing}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]